# Showing that $1-4^{a-1}\le4^{-a}$ in a simple way

Tags: inequality

Any ideas how to simply show that:
$$1-4^{a-1}\le4^{-a} \quad ,\,0\le a\le 1$$

When looking at the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6rAX.png) of the two functions it seems pretty straight forward, just show that:

1. They have a single intersection point at $a=1/2$
2. One of them is convex and the other one is concave (by taking their second derivatives)

Yet, I wonder if there's a simpler way to show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$4^a(1-4^{1-a})=4^a-4\leq4-4\leq1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$1-4^{a-1}\le4^{-a}$$

$$ -4^{-a}-4^{a-1}+1 \le 0 $$

$$ 4^{-a}+4^{a-1}-1 \ge 0 $$

$$ 1 + \frac{4^{2a}}{4} - 4^a \ge 0 $$

$$ 4+4^{2a}-4\cdot4^{a} \ge 0 $$

$$ (4^a-2)^2 \ge 0$$

Which is clearly true for $0\le a\le 1$

Answer (score 0):

Over $x\in[0,1]$
$$ 4^{-x}+4^{-(1-x)} \geq 4^{-1/2}+4^{-1/2} = 1 $$
since both $4^{-x}$ and $4^{-(1-x)}$ are convex functions.